# Reader is closed for some reason?

Tags: c#, mysql

**Fixed!** The version of the reference of Mysql.Data I was using was too old, I updated to the new one and it fixed it. Thanks anyway.

My SQL connection string is:

```
server=localhost; database=information_schema; uid=root; password=; convertzerodatetime=yes
```

And the query i'm trying to execute is:

```
"SELECT * FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'serenity'"
```

However, I'm using the following code:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Database.ConnectionString, query))
            {
                if (!reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Logger.WriteLog(Logger.LogTypes.Error, "Unable to populate meta.");
                    return;
                }

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                    }

                    this.Values.Add(new Datum(this.Table, dictionary));
                }
            }
```

and it throws an exception that the reader is closed. It's like it's failed to read for some reason. Why's that? I can manually connect to that database through other code, but it fails here for some reason. I'm trying to get all rows in table `COLUMNS` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` where the `TABLE_SCHEMA` is `serenity`. I do have those rows for sure. I'm able to connect to the database normally using connection.open, etc, but this execution throws an exception, why?

**The error thrown:**

```
Invalid attempt to Read when reader is closed. - MySqlException on the while loop.
```

Comment: can you show us exception and on what line it is thrown

Comment: are you using multiple threads..they may be simultaneously accessing the method..Also show us the exact error

Comment: @Anirudh I edited the op to what error it throws, and no, I don't use multiple threads.

Comment: @user2979962: post `MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader` code, please, and full code block for `using (MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader...`.

Comment: @Dennis http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelpermembers.html

Comment: @user2979962: I can't see any code, that closes reader explicitly, except `using` (I hope, that `MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader` doesn't close the reader as well). Which line causes exception **exactly**?